# C# azure : Thread abort exception while creating asset in media service

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-media-services

I'm using c# to create an asset in azure media service and link that to the blob in the storage account.

```
// Context created successfully

MediaServicesCredentials _cachedCredentials =
    new MediaServicesCredentials("MediaserviceName", "Mediaservicekey");

CloudMediaContext _context = new CloudMediaContext(_cachedCredentials);

// When i try to use below code to create an asset,
// it takes long time and finally getting Thread abort exception

IAsset asset = context.Assets.Create(assetName, AssetCreationOptions.None);
```

What could be the reason?

Edit:
I'm using .NET 4.5 in Xamarin 5.9.6, in Yosemite OS. And i just now found the same code is working fine in Visual Studio on windows OS system. Do i need any  update ?

Comment: This is almost certainly a timeout error. You should investigate *why* asset creation takes a long time. What type of application are you building? Eg IIS will kill requests that take a long time, even if the `Create` method doesn't throw itself.

Comment: I'm getting this time out exception when i use methods of "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client" framework. And trying to find the reason.

Comment: What environment? It is *very* important. Long running operations work differently in ASP.NET MVC, Web Forms a desktop application

Comment: Some things just take a long time - uploading the Lord Of The Rings trilogy for example. In this case you should use asynchronous methods like `CreateAsync` instead of Create

Comment: How long is the delay? `Create` simply creates an empty asset, it shouldn't take so much time that it times out. What else is going on in the code?

Comment: I'm using Xamarin 5.9.6, in Yosemite OS. And i just now found the same code is working fine in my windows system. Will edit the question. Thanks for the information.